# How to Get Substring of a string having elements in Consecutive Square Brackets using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following strings:
One Rule : Get all consecutive Square bracket strings : for example,

> string 1 : [hello][qwqwe:]sdsdfsdf [note2] 
>  string 2 :
>   [somethingelse]sdfsdf [note 1] 
>  string 3 : aasdad[note 3]

I would like to get the substrings :

> output 1 : [hello][qwqwe:] 
>  output 2 : [somethingelse] 
>  output
>   3 :

If the string doesn't have square brackets, I do not want an output.
If the string has a square bracket delimited string which is not consecutive, it should not match aswell.

I tried using the regex expression

> ([.*])*

But it matches everything between two square brackets. If you notice the first string, I do not need the part of the string that violates my rule.

Comment: You need to use the lazy match :  `[.*?]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this regular expression.

```
^(\[(.*?)\])*
```

C# code for matching:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"^(\[(.*?)\])*");

        var inputTexts = new string [] {"[abcd]xyz[pqrst]","abcd[xyz][pqr]","[asdf][abcd][qwer]sds[qwert]" };

        foreach (var match in inputTexts.Select(inputText => regex.Match(inputText)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }           

        //result1 - [abcd]
        //result2 -
        //result3 - [asdf][abcd][qwer]
```

Comment: [This matches the 3rd string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5c%5b(.*%3f)%5c%5d)*&i=aasdad%5bnote+3%5d).

Comment: yeah.. I should add ^ to match from the beginning of the String.

Comment: Choosing this as the answer as it gives the correct output for the string : 
[aasdad[note3]jhghjb
[link regex.com](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%5c%5b(.*%3f)%5c%5d)*&i=%5bhello%5d%5bqwqwe%3a%5d%5bjhbjhb%5dsdsdfsdf+%5bnote2%5d+%0d%0a%5bsomethingelse%5dsdfsdf+%5bnote+1%5d+%0d%0a%5baasdad%5bnote3%5djhghjb&o=nm)

Comment: I would avoid using lazy dot matching patterns since they are inefficient (you can test the speed at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester)). Character classes are always preferred when you have single-character delimiters. Note that `.` does not match a newline without the singleline modifier. Also, a `]` does not have to be escaped if used outside of a character class. Also, you do not use the capture groups, but specify them in the pattern creating additional overhead.

Answer (score 2):

## Approach 1: Matching multiple consecutive `[...]`s at string start *as a single string*

You need to use the following regex:

```
^(\[[^]]*])+
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5d*%5d)%2b&i=%5bhel%5b%5b%5blo%5d%5bqwq%5b%5b%5bwe%3a%5dsdsdfsdf+%5bnote2%5d+%0d%0a%5bsomethingelse%5dsdfsdf+%5bnote+1%5d+%0d%0aaasdad%5bnote+3%5d&o=nm)

The `^(\[[^]]*])+` matches:

- `^` - start of string (in the demo, it matches at line start due to the multiline modifier)
- `(\[[^]]*])+` - captured into Group 1 (you can access all of those values via `.Groups[1].Captures` collection) one or more occurrences of...

  - `\[` - a literal `[`
  - `[^]]*` - zero or more characters other than `]`
  - `]` - a literal `]`.

[C# code demo](http://ideone.com/fYxnE4):

```
var txt = "[hello][qwqwe:]sdsdfsdf [note2]";
var res = Regex.Match(txt, @"^(\[[^]]*])+"); // Run the single search
Console.WriteLine(res.Value); // Display the match
var captures = res.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", captures)); // Display captures
```

## Approach 2: Matching multiple consecutive `[...]`s at string start *separately*

You can use `\G` operator:

```
\G\[[^]]*]
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cG%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5d*%5d&i=%5bhel%5b%5blo%5d%5bqwq%5b%5bwe%3a%5dsdsdfsdf+%5bnote2%5d+)

It will match the `[...]` substrings at the start of the string and then after each successful match.

**Regex explanation**:

- `\G` - a zero-width assertion (anchor) matching the location at the beginning of a string, or after each successful match
- `\[[^]]*]` - a literal `[` (`\[`) followed by zero more (`*`) characters other than a `]`, followed by a closing `]`.

If you need to return a single string of all `[...]`s found at the beginning of the string, you need to concatenate the matches:

```
var txt = "[hello][qwqwe:]sdsdfsdf [note2]";
var res = Regex.Matches(txt, @"\G\[[^]]*]").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", res));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WnrVKZ)

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Your answer was really great and your reasoning was spot on. But I did not mention in the question if '[' ']' should not be present within a substring which was delimited by square brackets.

For egs : Consider the String : 
[aasdad[note3]jhghjb
This should match : [aasdad[note3] 
But your answer would break for this case,  so I had to chose the answer by @SarinVT which does not break for this case aswell.

Comment: All you need to change in my answer is remove the `[` in the character class. I updated the answer and all links in it.

Comment: Yes, I know. But he did find the answer first and would surely deserve some credit. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust four things from you original regex to make it work: 1) use non-greedy match `.*?`, 2) add `^` to match from beginning of string, 3) escape the square brackets, and 4) change final `*` to `+` to require at least one group of square brackets:

```
^(\[.*?\])+
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works for me with your test strings.

```
^(\[[^\]]*(\]|\]\[))*
```

Explanation generated by https://regex101.com/ :

```
1st Capturing group (\[[^\]]*(\]|\]\[))*
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
\[ matches the character [ literally
[^\]]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\] matches the character ] literally
2nd Capturing group (\]|\]\[)
1st Alternative: \]
\] matches the character ] literally
2nd Alternative: \]\[
\] matches the character ] literally
\[ matches the character [ literally
```